# Trace requests for net.tcp on IIS 7.0

Tags: .net, wcf, iis-7

I have wcf application which hosted on IIS 7 using net.tcp binding. I want to catch all requests(with raw body information) to this application using IIS or other stuff. How can I do this ?

Thank to all.